# ask user name and check if length is between 3 and 256 characters

Tags: java

I'm new in coding and I'm trying to have the user input his name and if the user's name is not between 3 and 256, he have to re enter his name!
Here's my code so far...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String userName = "";        
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter your name (between 3 and 256 characters) :");
        Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
        userName = name.nextLine();

        if ((userName.length() < 3) && (userName.length() > 256));
            System.out.println("the length is not good");

    } while ((userName.length() < 3) && (userName.length() > 256));

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Poor Xi.  His name won't be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in

```
if ((userName.length() < 3) && (userName.length() > 256));
    System.out.println("the length is not good");
```

Remove the semicolon on the first line

Change `&&` to `||`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userName = "";
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter your name (between 3 and 256 characters):");
            Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
            userName = name.nextLine();
        if ((userName.length() < 3) && (userName.length() > 256));
            System.out.println("the length is not good");
        } while ((userName.length() < 3) && (userName.length() > 256));
    }
```

This will not work! You have wrong syntax in your if statement.

```
    if ((userName.length() < 3) && (userName.length() > 256));
        System.out.println("the length is not good");
```

Should be:

```
   if (userName.length() < 3 || userName.length() > 256) {
       System.out.println("the length is not good");
   }
```

And the while part of the do while should be:

```
   while (userName.length() < 3 || userName.length() > 256);
```